# What permissions should have wicked_pdf on the rails tmp folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, wicked-pdf

I have installed wicked_pdf on my rails 4 project. I have it running under nginx and passenger on my Ubuntu 16 EC2 machine.

When i try to generate a PDF in 'production' i get the following error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /.../tmp/cache):
```

Off course it will work if i chmod -R 777 my tmp folder but i don't want to fix it in this way.

While searching i've found that i should chown the folder to www-data user; i've tried it without luck, maybe the process that generates the PDF should have permission over this folder?

Thanks in advance

Edit, added the trace:

```
App 17963 stdout: ***************WICKED***************
App 17963 stdout:   Rendered posts/article.pdf.erb within layouts/article_pdf.html.erb (0.9ms)
App 17963 stdout: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
App 17963 stdout: 
App 17963 stdout: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - xxx/.../tmp/cache):
App 17963 stdout:     3: <head>
App 17963 stdout:     4:    <title></title>
App 17963 stdout:     5:    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
App 17963 stdout:     6:     <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
App 17963 stdout:     7:     <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'social' %>
App 17963 stdout:     8:     <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'directories' %>
App 17963 stdout:     9:    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'home' %>
App 17963 stdout:   app/views/layouts/article_pdf.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_article_pdf_html_erb__3815099653923299167_60691780'
App 17963 stdout:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:167:in `block (2 levels) in article'
App 17963 stdout:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:164:in `article'
App 17963 stdout: 
App 17963 stdout: 
App 17963 stdout: Processing by ErrorsController#internal_server_error as PDF
```

Edit 2:
This error comes up each time i precompile my assets and restart my nginx server. It seems that each time i precompile my assets the tmp folder content is recreated by root.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: @Tai , updated.. thanks!

Comment: As the stack trace, I think that this error happen when Sprocket compile the assets. But in production, assets should be precompiled, not compile on runtime. Can you check the configuration? Also, can you try to delete `tmp` folder so that web app process can recreate it to correct the permission?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I forgot to mention that this happens after i precompile my assets. Maybe i got a misconfiguration? . Each time i run rake assets:precompile and restart my nginx server this error comes up, i am only able to fix it by granting horrible permissions to the tmp folder.

Comment: If you have already precompiled assets, they shouldn't be compiled at runtime. Is `assets.compile` `true` or `false`? I suggest to change it to `false` then try again.

Comment: @Tai Thanks!, at the moment assets.compile is in true, i will change it to false. But this have not fixed the issue :(

Comment: I lie, it works and i have not set any permissions after precompiling the assets. I do not understand why this works?, please explain in the answers and i will mark you as Accepted

Comment: Good to know that you already resolved your issue. Update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should grant the permissions for user that run Passenger or sidekiq. To find that user you can use below command:

```
ps -aux | grep "sidekiq\|Passenger"
```

**Edit (Update the root cause):**

The root cause is that wicket_pdf detect that it should precompile assets while in production, assets are already precompiled and it shouldn't try to compile them anymore.

Set `assets.compile` to `true` force wicket_pdf to use precompiled ones. The code to check whether it should use compiled assets or not is [here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/8439a045c8df15486beb9a06e58c8343abbe816a/lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper/assets.rb#L100).

Comment: Thanks, i see that for both of them are root